# Add conditions on Where in Views 3

Tags: views

How can I do to add more conditions on WHERE, like this 
WHERE view conditions ... **AND ( (sentence 1 AND sentence 2) or (sentence 3 AND sentence 4) or ... )**
This view is in a user profile and this conditions depens on profile data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the option you need is in the "Filter Criteria" section, in the dropdown next to the "Add" button. If you fold down that menu you will see the "And/Or, Rearrange" option in which you can create sets of conditions.

Comment: It's a good solution but my problem is that query modification must be done in code.

Comment: Ah ok, then please update your question with some code and explain what you have tried.